# .contains doesnt work like i thought it would Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, pls

I am very new to Flutter and I run into a Problem. I want to check if the **List: items**, contains the word
**Hey** and I know it does. So I wrote: `if(items.contains('Hey'))` to check. But it seems to skip the `if` part and only returns the else part. I wrote this easy Code to show you what I mean. I would really appreciate
a quick answer, because of I really need to solve this problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Contain()));

class Liste {
  String Wort1;
  String Wort2;

  Liste({this.Wort1, this.Wort2});
}

class Contain extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContainState createState() => _ContainState();
}

class _ContainState extends State<Contain> {
  List<Liste> items = List<Liste>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    items = [
      Liste(Wort1: 'Hey', Wort2: 'Ho'),
      Liste(Wort1: 'HA', Wort2: 'HE'),
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  function() {
    if (items.contains('Hey')) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('Works'),
      );
    } else {
      return Center(
        child: Text('Not Working'),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      body: function(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you read the documentation you will see the following:

> Returns true if the collection contains an element equal to `element`.
>
> ...
>
> The equality used to determine whether `element` is equal to an element of the iterable defaults to the `Object.==` of the element.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Iterable/contains.html

So when you try do to `if (items.contains('Hey'))` it returns false since no object in your list are equal to `'Hey'`. Actually, `'Hey'` is a String and your list contains `Liste` objects.

A better way to do what your are trying to do is to use [`.any`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Iterable/any.html) like this which will iterate over your list and run a check for each element to check if any element returns true:

```
    if (items.any((e) => e.Wort1 == 'Hey' || e.Wort2 == 'Hey')) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('Works'),
      );
    }
```

Alternative you can implement the `==` operator on `Liste` to actually return `true` if comparing to a `String` like this:

```
class Liste {
  String Wort1;
  String Wort2;

  Liste({this.Wort1, this.Wort2});
  
  bool operator ==(other) {
    if (other is String) {
      return other == Wort1 || other == Wort2;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

By the way, please don't name variables with first letter as capital.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was really helpful !